# powershell script add-adgroupmember

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

I'm writing a script which is supposed to show me security groups by matching an input e.g. 'marketing'.

Afterwards I want to add a user to this security group. Since the exchange-powershell can search for user via `-anr` it's much easier to find the right person.

Here is the part of my script:

```
$grparray = get-adgroup -filter * | where { $_.name -match "marketing" -and $_.GroupCategory -eq 'Security' }
$potentarray = get-mailbox -anr Julia | select SamAccoutName

$grparray[1] | add-adgroupmember -members $potentarray[1]
```

But I get the error:

> CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.AcitveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddAdGroupMember

Seems like the ad-modules can't handle the Exchange input.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue, or got another idea how to?

Comment: Can you try Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $grparray[1] -Members $potentarray[1] instead ?

Comment: Instead of using Get-Mailbox, try `$potentarray = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=Julia)"`

Comment: With the first attempt i get the exact same error.

Comment: But with James' solution it works fine. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambiguous Name Resolution is available with `Get-ADUser`, this is preferable over `Get-Mailbox` as it returns an AD Object which can be used as an input for `Add-ADGroupmember`.

Try `$potentarray = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=Julia)"` instead of Get-Mailbox.